# Kotlin Gradle project, getting NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Ref$ObjectRef

Tags: kotlin, gradle, noclassdeffounderror

My Kotlin code is giving me a NoClassDefFoundError and I can't see what is causing it.
When I compile with 'gradle clean build' and execute the .jar file it gives me the following error,

```
    at xyz.colmmurphy.ktop.KtopKt.main(ktop.kt:16)
    at xyz.colmmurphy.ktop.KtopKt.main(ktop.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.jvm.internal.Ref$ObjectRef
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

I've looked through my code dozens of times and I still can't where the bug is

```
package xyz.colmmurphy.ktop

import java.io.File
import kotlin.collections.*

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import xyz.colmmurphy.ktop.stat.CPUReader
import kotlin.system.exitProcess

fun main() {
    if (!File("/proc/stat").exists()) {
        println("couldn't find /proc/stat")
        exitProcess(1)
    }
    lateinit var initJiffies : HashMap<Int, List<Int>>
    lateinit var endJiffies : HashMap<Int, List<Int>>
    GlobalScope.launch {
        initJiffies = CPUReader.readCPUUsage()
    }

    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(4000L)
        endJiffies = CPUReader.readCPUUsage()
    }

    println("waiting...")
    Thread.sleep(6000L)
    println(CPUReader.calculateCPUUsage(initJiffies, endJiffies))

    val foo = CPUReader.usagePerCore(initJiffies, endJiffies)
    for (i in foo) {
        println("cpu${i.key} -> ${i.value}%")
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: This is what the CPUReader class looks like

```
package xyz.colmmurphy.ktop.stat

import java.io.File

object CPUReader {
    suspend fun readCPUUsage(): HashMap<Int, List<Int>> {
        val hm = HashMap<Int, List<Int>>()

        val statLines = File("/proc/stat").bufferedReader()
        statLines.readLine() // skips the first line in the file

        val cpus = ArrayList<CPUCore>()
        var nextLine = statLines.readLine()
        while (nextLine.startsWith("cpu")) {
            cpus.add(CPUCore(nextLine))
            nextLine = statLines.readLine()
        }
        for (i in cpus) {
            var workJiffies = 0
            var totalJiffies = 0
            val info = i.infoList
            for (j in 0 until 2) workJiffies += info[j].toInt()
            for (j in 0 until 9) totalJiffies += info[j].toInt()
            hm[i.corenum] = listOf(workJiffies, totalJiffies)
        }
        return hm
    }

    fun calculateCPUUsage(initJiffies: HashMap<Int, List<Int>>, endJiffies: HashMap<Int, List<Int>>): String {
        var totalWorkJiffies = 0
        var totalJiffies = 0

        for (i in endJiffies) {
            totalWorkJiffies += i.value[0]
            totalJiffies += i.value[1]
        }
        for (i in initJiffies) {
            totalWorkJiffies -= i.value[0]
            totalJiffies -= i.value[1]
        }

        return ((totalWorkJiffies.toFloat().div(totalJiffies) * 100)).toString() + "%"
    }
    fun usagePerCore(initJiffies: HashMap<Int, List<Int>>, endJiffies: HashMap<Int, List<Int>>): HashMap<Int, Float> {
        val perCoreUsage = HashMap<Int, Float>()

        for (i in initJiffies) {
            perCoreUsage[i.key] = ((endJiffies[i.key]!![0] - i.value[0]).toFloat().div(endJiffies[i.key]!![1] - i.value[1])) * 100F
        }

        return perCoreUsage
    }
}
```

and the CPUCore class

```
package xyz.colmmurphy.ktop.stat

import java.io.File
import java.lang.Exception

class CPUCore (val info: String) {
    val corenum : Int = try {
        info.toCharArray()[3].toString().toInt()
    } catch (e: Exception) { 0 }
    var infoList = File("/proc/stat").bufferedReader().readLines()[corenum + 1].substring(5).split(" ")
        get() = File("/proc/stat").bufferedReader().readLines()[corenum + 1].substring(5).split(" ")
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details about `CPUReader` class? I tried your code in an online REPL commenting out any statement that references that class and it runs without errors - so maybe the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception is triggered when loading `CPUReader`...

Comment: I have edited the original post to add the information about the CPUReader class

Comment: Ok, thank you! If you can add the `CPUCore` class (and maybe its dependencies...), too, we can run your code ourself and trye to identify the problem...

Comment: I have added the CPUCore class as well but I don't think it is very basic and I don't think it is causing the problem

Comment: Hi @Colm, I was able to run your code properly, both through IntelliJ IDEA and using Gradle from CLI. More in detai, I'm using Gradle 6.6.1 over OpenJDK 15 and my project is linking `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.30` and `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2`. What version are you using? What about try with a configuration similar to mine, in order to test if it'a a version compatibility problem?

Comment: @PietroMartinelli I am using Gradle 6.8, openJDK15 and kotlin 1.3, with ```"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2"``` I can run the program without any problems from intelliJ IDEA but I got a NoClassDefFoundError when I run the .jar file

Comment: Ok. The jar file you are referring ti is the jar created by gradle jar? Did you run it specifying the dependencies list through java -jar thejar.jar -classpath kotlinx-coroutines-core.jar:.... ?